# An economical problem or an economic problem?

Tags: adverbs

The confusion occurred as both are adjectives. Months back, one of the native speakers here corrected me when I said...

> I asked about the <del>economical</del> economic problems of the nation.

I think it's fine using 'adjective' economical, isn't it? As I often hear, *His [financial condition is not good](http://www.cvt-news.com/news/?p=6898) **NOT** His finance condition is not good.*

Your views please.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/economic-vs-economical.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Oh, it's asked! I did Google but ESE din' come up on the result.

Answer (score 2):

Economic means related to the economy  as a whole.

- the economic trends of Germany are stable.

Economical refers to something which is done taking care not to waste money or time.

- an economical style of life.

so "economic"  is the right word for your sentence.

Comment: *economical* means related to economy and it's adjective. What about the financial condition? Do you use 'finance condition' as it's the similar usage.

Comment: "financial conditions" of a country, refer to the state of the balance of money a State can use to provide services to people or paying for public works. The main revenue source for a modern State is tax collection or National Debt issue. hope it can help.

Comment: What do you think about this sentence: *aspects of social, political, and economical life*

Comment: ...and economic life!

Comment: no. *economical* is correctly used there. I confirmed it. I read this answer carefully and it clarifies it better. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9545/economic-vs-economical

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree... I work in finance...and economic is the term we use. Economical may be correct also but it is rarely used  when you speak about the economy. Your choice!!!

Comment: A book on it - http://www.abebooks.co.uk/Johnsons-Notes-North-America-Agricultural-Social/209435927/bd But yes, *economic* life is more common. Agreed.

Comment: I have never heard a professional using 'economical' referring to economic issues. I suggest you avoid it..it sounds awkward though it can be easily understood.

Comment: Sure. I will avoid it considering that you work in finance. I just 'unaccepted' the answer so to avoid misguiding others. As, 'economical' the way I used is *not incorrect*

Answer (score 0):

The choice of the two adjectives depends on the context and professional preferences of a interlocutor. Some professions have developed strict requirements for the usage and use of many terms.
The words *economic* and *economical* are synonyms morphologically.
If you are not a student of a certain profession and you talked at a table in a cafe on a sunny day, then your interlocutor did not like something and he decided to take you up a bit by snubbing you a little.

Answer (score -1):

English adjectives ending in -ic or -ical are a real problem. There is no
system in it and if one looks more carefully into this matter one finds
various sorts of types. One might say in this matter language has gone wild.

PS Well, to add some examples:

Type practical
There is only one adjective in -ical. Of the same type impractical,
theoretical, hypothetical.These adjectives have no noun of the type *practic etc.

Type logical
There is the noun the logic. The adj is logical. There is no adj *logic.

Type economical + economic
Both adjectives exist with different meaning, The normal adj is economic.
economical means a good ratio between cost and result.

Type classic + classical
There is the noun "a classic" and both adjectives. The use is difficult.
I made a note for myself: Look up the dictionary when you have to use one of these adjectives.

Remark
This is no extensive study. This is only meant to show that adjectives in -ic/ical
are a problem.

Comment: other examples?